# ActiveRecord callback setup from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have to simple models `First` and `Second`, and there is one to one relationship from `Second` using `belongs_to :first`. Now I want to do something with `Second`, when `First` is saved. But I don't want to setup an `after_save` callback in `First`, to deal with `Second`.

I want to keep my models clean, and unaware of each other as much as possible. I'm always following best practices in object encapsulation, and it makes my life easier, always.

So naturally, since `after_save` is a class method, I tried to setup this callback in `Second`, like this:

```
class Second < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :first

  First.after_save do |record|
    if that = Second.find_by_first_id(record.id)
      # grow magic mushrooms here...
    end
  end
end
```

but this doesn't work, that callback is never executed, and no error is raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be best to set up an [observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html), something like "FirstObserver" and write an after-save callback there.

Comment: Indeed, observer is solution to my problem, I didn't know about their existence, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may do it via observer:

```
class FirstObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(first)
    ...
  end
end
```

Don't forget to enable observer in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.observers = :first_observer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
First.class_eval do
  def after_save record
     #mashrooooms
  end
end
```